# Lightning Component permissions

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, permissions

I have a Lightning Component button that calls some Apex methods.  The same methods are called in classic by a standard button.

In classic, both administrators and regular users are able to use the button and its called methods.

In LEX, I as administrator can use the LC button, but when regular users attempt to use the LC button the process simply hangs with the six-dot spinner showing on the screen.  It will stay there until the pop-up is cancelled or Accept is pressed.

It looks like a permissions issue, but I cannot find anywhere where the user profile is not set properly.

Can anyone point me to a fix for this?  Or how to take the troubleshooting process further?

Thanks.

Bryan Hunt

Comment: Is the Apex controller that is referenced in the LC accessible to the user profiles?

Comment: Are you aware of this critical update?  https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2020/critical-update-ensure-users-have-access-to-auraenabled-methods

Comment: The Class that contains the Apex @AuraEnabled methods is in the Enabled Apex Class Access list, so that does not appear to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It took some digging, but I was able to solve this issue.

The LC buttons were converted JavaScript buttons from Salesforce classic.  That conversion process generates some LC helper classes during the conversion process.  Apparently the process added the helper classes to the System Administrator profile automatically.  Once I added the helper classes to the Enabled Apex Class Access list for each of the user profiles, all worked perfectly.

Thanks for the responses.

Bryan Hunt